# springboot admin: How to display custom metrics in springboot admin GUI ("Metrics" tab)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-admin

We are using serveral microservices with springboot (Vers. 1.4.3) and for monitoring them springboot-admin (Vers. 1.5.0).

Inside our microservices we generate several custom metrics (using the 
'@com.codahale.metrics.annotation.Timed' annotation).

While all these custom metrics are displayed through the ordinary actuator-endpoint "/metrics" they are sorrowly not shown in the springboot admin GUI -"Metrics" tab.

Obviously only "counter.*" and "gauge.*" metrics are displayed in the latter.

Is there any possibility to configure / modify springboot admin, so that these custom metrics also are shown - either in the existing 'metrics' tab or in another new tab ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, meanwhile I found out, that the new  springboot-admin version 1.5.2 will solve our problem:

As I could see at a project from a colleague, this springboot-admin version will display ALL metrics without any restrictions regarding the metrics-key.

[ At the moment we can't upgrade to this version since our springboot-version dependency prevents it but in the future we'll be able to do so.]

So the problem is more or less solved.